# Print Preview for printing windows form not working in C#

Tags: c#, printing, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to screen capture a windows form, provide a print preview and then print it. The form is printing on paper but the prin preview displays the message "Document does not contain any pages"/

Here are the relevant snippets from my code. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
 Bitmap bmp; // Variable for Bitmap of actual page to print

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) //Click to Print
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        bmp = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height, g);
        Graphics mg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        mg.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, this.Size);
        //printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        //printDocument1.Print();

        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
      //  printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
     {
          e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);



    }
```

Comment: Problem solved, not sure how.